# How do you install memcache

Tags: xampp

I need to install memcache on my dev server,

I am using Xampp on Windows

I have read a few sites that say you uncomment these lines in the php.ini file for xampp which I have done

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
[Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
memcache.chunk_size =8192
memcache.default_port = 11211
```

Then it says:

> Then head to Jellycan Code http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/ and
>   download the **Windows memcached port
>   (binary)**. At this point you should be
>   able to launch the .exe and run the
>   sample code above.

I have done all this and I cannot fine a single .exe file in the memcache package, I tried downloading ALL the memcache packages and checked them all and cannot find any exe files, and I don't think I am overlooking it as I searched the folder with 0 results.

Also every site I have read on how to install memcache on xampp give these same directions, please help someone

Comment: You downloaded this file? http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip All it has is an exe inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip](http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip) contains a `.exe` file, infact it only contains a `.exe` file?

Comment: That's wright. You must have gotten the source files archive instead of the binary one.